# Transactions in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I new to hibernate

In  my project, i need to handle transactions. 
How to handle declarative transactions with in two classes

Examples:

```
//class 1
class A{

  createA()
  {
    insert(A);
  }
}

//class 2
class B
{
  createB()
  {
    insert(B);
  }
}

//class 3
@Transaction(Exception.class)

class C
{

  test()
  {

    create(A);

    create(B);

  }
}
```

As per the above code is there any possibility to handle transactions, in such a way that if the insert in classA success and the insert in the classB fails then the transaction should rollback and remove the record inserted in the table A corresponding to the Class A

please help me with this using declarative transactions....

Thanks in adavace....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate like anything else supports transaction. So you just need to wrap calls to update() and save() in a transaction.

Example:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();

    // your updates to the database
    create(A);
    create(B);


    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

And you get your wish. If anything fails between beginTransaction() and commit(), everything is rolled back.

You might have questions about session handling, but that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks Milenkoski, iam trying to use declarative transacrtion , so could you please help me in that way

Comment: No difference. When you annotate a method @Transaction it will wrap the whole method in a transaction. So less boilerplate...

Comment: Mikenkiski, could you please help me with an example, i tried wrapping the method with transaction annotation but no use. The record is being insert when the second insert failed

Comment: If you are using Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html

Comment: If you are using EJB, with Container Managed Transaction, you need to set:

1. hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class to a lookup strategy for your JEE container

2. set hibernate.transaction.factory_class to org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory

Comment: Thanks Milenkoski, i am using spring 3